# What types of attributes does the dir function give in python?

Tags: python-2.7

I read somewhere that everything in python is an object. I thought, how about the number 2? If I type "dir(2)" into the python interpreter, I get the following output:

> > > dir(2)
> > >       ['__abs__', '__add__', '__and__', '__class__', '__cmp__', '__coerce__', '__delattr__', '__div__', '__divmod__', '__doc__', '__float__', '__floordiv__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__getnewargs__', '__hash__', '__hex__', '__index__', '__init__', '__int__', '__invert__', '__long__', '__lshift__', '__mod__', '__mul__', '__neg__', '__new__', '__nonzero__', '__oct__', '__or__', '__pos__', '__pow__', '__radd__', '__rand__', '__rdiv__', '__rdivmod__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__rfloordiv__', '__rlshift__', '__rmod__', '__rmul__', '__ror__', '__rpow__', '__rrshift__', '__rshift__', '__rsub__', '__rtruediv__', '__rxor__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__sub__', '__subclasshook__', '__truediv__', '__trunc__', '__xor__', 'bit_length', 'conjugate', 'denominator', 'imag', 'numerator', 'real']

Evidently the number 2 is an object with these attributes. I get several names of attributes the number 2, like __add__ and conjugate. But if I try 2.conjugate(), I get an error

2.conjugate()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

However dir(2j) has conjugate as a method and I do not get an error when I use the method conjugate.

2j.conjugate()
-2j

and

2.0.conjugate() 
2.0

also gives me no problems.

More weird things, 2.__add__() and 2.__add__ gives an error even though it is an attribute of 2. I think **add** refers to the + operation. So why does it show up as __add__ in the list of attributes and not as +? Is dir(2) the list of variables and methods of 2 or does it list other things? What is the difference between __thing__ and thing? When can you call a method the regular way, like object.method() and when do you have to do funky things like 2+2 instead of 2.add(2)?

Answer (score 1):

`conjugate` *is* a method of `int`, which can be applied to int objects.

To demonstrate, all of these work:

```
x = 2; x.conjugate()
(2).conjugate()
2 .conjugate()  # note the whitespace
```

Since the python parser has special handlings of numeric literals, it doesn't allow this awkward syntax:

```
 2.conjugate()
```

As explained by @ignacio, this is because the parser sees `2.` and treats it as a float, i.e. like `(2.)conjugate()`, which is not a valid syntax.

However, other than using it with this syntax, the operation is allowed, as demonstrated above.

As for `__add__`, the `__add__` method allows types to define/override how the `+` opertor applies to them.  When you do `a+b`, the interpreter invokes either `a.__add__(b)` or `b.__add__(a)` (the mechanism is more complex than that).

Ordinarily, you shouldn't have to call `__add__` directly.

Answer (score 0):

The parser sees the "." and thinks that a float is expected.

```
>>> (2).conjugate
<built-in method conjugate of int object at 0x2242140>
```

For the rest:

[Python Language Reference, Data Model section](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html)

Comment: Technically speaking it's the lexer rather than the parser that makes the lower-level decisions about what constitutes a source "token". Since `2.` is a valid token, the parser never gets to see the period.